# Linux join with multiple lines?

Tags: linux, join

I am attempting to use join as a renumbering function.

File 1:

```
A
B
A
B
```

File 2:

```
A 1
B 2
```

Desired output:

```
A 1
B 2
A 1
B 2
```

Join does not seem capable. I have tried:

```
join -1 1 -2 1 -a 1 -a 2 file1 file2
```

And other variations.

Comment: Does the order of lines matter?

Comment: Order does not matter as long as they match across rows appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the files if there are not sorted in itself and join,

```
join -j 1 -o 1.1,2.2  <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Taken from the Linux man page of join(1):

```
-j FIELD
   equivalent to '-1 FIELD -2 FIELD'

-o FORMAT
   obey FORMAT while constructing output line
```